# Oracle APEX : How to change value in a switch column in Interactive Grid (using dynamic action - JavaScript)?

Tags: oracle-apex

My Interactive Grid SQL Query's last column (USER_EXIST) is of Switch Type with possible Values Yes / No. Based on existing logic, I have a variable (l_new_val) which holds a value (dynamically) which I want to set to the USER_EXIST column. For ex, if l_new_val = 'Y', I want to assign 'Y' to all records with USER_EXIST = 'N'. How can I do this using dynamic action - JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

If you know this value when the page load, you could assign set it as the default value for that column. Either as a function returning it or creating a hidden page item holding it to be referenced by the columns.

You could grab the switch every time one is created. I'm not sure that would be an easy task. Maybe using the mode change and then navigating the dome from this.triggeringElement.